# Dual boot (2x Linux), safe to delete the first one?

Tags: partition, dual-boot

I have installed two Linux distributions, HDD partitioned in 2 parts. First Ubuntu, second Debian, if that matters.

After working with both, I have decided to keep Debian, and get rid of Ubuntu (recovering the space, of course).

If I start gparted from a live-USB, can I just delete the Ubuntu partition and expand the Debian partition?

It's a legacy boot mode.

Answer (score 1):

> If I start gparted from a live-USB, can I just delete the Ubuntu partition and expand the Debian partition?

1. grub is managed from debian.

Yes

2. grub is managed from Ubuntu .

You need to reinstall grub , see [Rescue Live](https://wiki.debian.org/RescueLive).